# How to post checkbox that are unchecked In CI?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, checkbox

Here, My html view for multiple checkbox :

[image]

Html for check box is like below

**For A_I Checkbox**

```
<input type="hidden" name="auto_number[]" id="auto_numberhidden" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="auto_number[]" id="auto_number" value="1" />
```

**For Not Display IN Form Checkbox**

```
<input type="hidden" name="not_show_in_form[]" id="not_show_in_formhidden" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="not_show_in_form[]" id="not_show_in_form" value="1" />
```

Here is my CI function for **add** table data :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            $name_col = $this->input->post('name_col');
            $type_col = $this->input->post('type_col');
            $length_values_col = $this->input->post('length_values_col');
            $index_col = $this->input->post('index_col');
            $auto_number = $this->input->post('auto_number');
            $not_show_in_form = $this->input->post('not_show_in_form');
            $createTable = $post = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_col); $i++) {
                $createTable['fields'][] = array(
                    'name_field' => $name_col[$i],
                    'type_field' => $type_col[$i],
                    'length_field' => $length_values_col[$i],
                    'index_field' => $index_col[$i],
                    'auto_field' => $auto_number[$i],
                    'not_show_in_form' => $not_show_in_form[$i]
                );
            }
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($createTable);die;
}
```

When I'm submit my form, It will give me form array like :

```
    Array
(
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name_field] => id
                    [type_field] => INT
                    [length_field] => 11
                    [index_field] => PRIMARY
                    [auto_field] => 0
                    [not_show_in_form] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name_field] => name
                    [type_field] => VARCHAR
                    [length_field] => 20
                    [index_field] => 
                    [auto_field] => 1
                    [not_show_in_form] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name_field] => gender
                    [type_field] => VARCHAR
                    [length_field] => 10
                    [index_field] => 
                    [auto_field] => 0
                    [not_show_in_form] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name_field] => created_date
                    [type_field] => DATE
                    [length_field] => 
                    [index_field] => 
                    [auto_field] => 0
                    [not_show_in_form] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

**Issue:**

Here, **id** field have two check value i.e. A_I and Not Display IN Form and **created_date** have only Not Display IN Form.
According to my form my array like as below, But it give me above array.

```
Array
(
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name_field] => id
                    [type_field] => INT
                    [length_field] => 11
                    [index_field] => PRIMARY
                    [auto_field] => 1
                    [not_show_in_form] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name_field] => name
                    [type_field] => VARCHAR
                    [length_field] => 20
                    [index_field] => 
                    [auto_field] => 0
                    [not_show_in_form] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name_field] => gender
                    [type_field] => VARCHAR
                    [length_field] => 10
                    [index_field] => 
                    [auto_field] => 0
                    [not_show_in_form] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name_field] => created_date
                    [type_field] => DATE
                    [length_field] => 
                    [index_field] => 
                    [auto_field] => 0
                    [not_show_in_form] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

How can I fixed my array.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your problem is because of this - <input type="hidden" name="auto_number[]" id="auto_numberhidden" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="auto_number[]" id="auto_number" value="1" />. The hidden input and checkbox, both have the same name though different ids. So in the first item in array, for column 'id', you get hidden values for both auto increment as well as not show in form. And in second item in array, you get checked values. You need to give these different names too.

Comment: @T.Shah, you are right ... but how can I manage that different name in my $createTable Array ?

Comment: The simplest way would be - 'auto_field' => $auto_number[$i+1],
                    'not_show_in_form' => $not_show_in_form[$i+1]

Comment: It  will not give proper array  as per my requirement..@T.Shah . For Id fields it will add both checkbox value but in created_date my checkbox is checked for not show in form still it will give me 0.

Comment: Why? I think it should work. Or you can declare a variable named $j in the loop like this - $j= $i+1; And then , 'auto_field' => $auto_number[$j],
                    'not_show_in_form' => $not_show_in_form[$j].

Comment: @T.Shah,  getting same problem Not get proper array that i want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156651/discussion-between-t-shah-and-angel).

Comment: It would be - like for 0th item in array - checkbox index that we want is 1, for 1st item in array it should be - checkbox index 3 and so on. So $j should be $j=$i+$i+1;